# How to handle a specific assertEquals-Error for casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to catch an assertEqualsError and handle it. For example:

```
var innerHTML =  casper.getElementInfo(x('id("grid")/a[2]')).html;
test.assertEquals(innerHTML, "GridContent",
function success(){
},function fail(){
    captureSelector('screenshots/error%D%.png'.replace('%D%',25), x(id("grid")));
});
```

This example doesn't work. The casper code is generated and the fail function should generate a screenshot of the parent-element of the not matching element.

The screenshot have to be with an incremented number and should (if possible) throw an error including the line of the test.

Comment: example is derived by the waitForSelector fail function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tester#assertEquals` doesn't have a success or fail callback, because it is not asynchronous. It's a little tricky to get to that information, but you can register an event handler that does that for you:

```
casper.on("fail", function(ev){
    if (ev.type === "assertEquals") {
        captureSelector('screenshots/error%D%.png'.replace('%D%',25), x(id("grid")));
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that this is a global event handler that you cannot remove without using some undocumented CasperJS feature. But if you want this to be more reusable, you can make it like this:

```
var failFunc = null;
casper.on("fail", function(ev){
    if (typeof failFunc === "function" && ev.type === "assertEquals") {
        failFunc();
        failFunc = null;
    }
});

...

casper.then(function(){
    failFunc = function(){
        captureSelector('screenshots/error%D%.png'.replace('%D%',25), x(id("grid")));
    };

    test.assertEquals(innerHTML, "GridContent")
});
```